# Names for someone who make bows (for shooting arrows)

Tags: single-word-requests

My feeling is that *bow-maker* is the only current word for this meaning. Any others?

The context is translation from a Chinese sutra (*Fǎjù jīng* 14.7):

> 弓工調角 Bow-makers master horn —
>
> 水人調船 watermen master boats —
>
> 材匠調木 carpenters master wood —
>
> 智者調身 the wise master themselves.

There's an old word *bowyer* that I fear is extinct. Current *bower* is easily confused with a lot of other meanings: shaded resting place, one who bows at the waist, one who plays an instrument with a bow, anchors suspended from the bow of a boat.

A *fletcher* is primarily an arrow-maker (from French *flèche* 'arrow'), but the OED has a sixteenth-century example where it seems to mean someone who makes bows.

There's also a defunct word *artiller* for this meaning.

Comment: [**Fletcher** – arrow maker **Bowyer** – bow maker](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Fletcher+%E2%80%93+arrow+maker+Bowyer+%E2%80%93+bow+maker%22)

Comment: Whilst the context is ... questionable ... I've found _bowyer_ in "current" use, by medievalist and pseudomedievalist organizations such as the Society for Creative Anachronism. Any 'extinctness' is most likely due to the fact that the role itself is mostly extinct.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Yes, I fear taking philological usage as evidence of currency when I hope to satisfy a general readership. A problem with using a word that is correct but rare is that it distracts attention from elsewhere in the text.

Comment: I suspect that the only reason _bowyer_ feels archaic and un-used is because archery is not as popular as it once was.  It's similar to how _farrier_ is no longer a common word because few people ride or care for horses any more.  And, like riding horses, at least here in the US, we've eschewed archery in favor of more efficient means of killing each other, leaving bows and arrows to the hobbyist.

Comment: I tend to agree that "bowyer" is archaic or historical, and there is no other alternative than "bow-maker" The OED puts "bowyer" in the same frequency category as **ebullition, amortizable, prelapsarian, contumacious, and argentiferous**. That said, the use of "master" (archaic) in the original, and the context of "ancient folk-wisdom" could possibly allow "bowyer".

Comment: I expect *bowyer* will show a peak in usage recently as it is used in the video game Ghost of Tsushima, which was released July of this year.

Comment: Bowyer is in current use and well known, it is neither extinct nor unknown.There are numerous bowyers still working and making bows. Bower is a word used for them in Scotland. In the UK there is a Craft Guild of Traditional Bowyers and Fletchers which has been operating for over 30 years, making traditional equipment. There are London Guilds of both Bowyers and Fletchers, with histories going back to when the bow was in use in warfare. Although now largely charitable organisations they engage with and support many archery activities, including the work of the modern Craft Guild. Archery is The

Comment: Thanks, Veronica, but the answer 'bowyer' has already been given, so this should be a supporting comment rather than a duplicate 'answer'. And yes, the 50-rep requirement has frustrated all new visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the definition of **bowyer** in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bowyer) shows only a single sense:

> : a maker of shooting bows
>
> Zeljko Ilicic, *bowyer*, a maker of wooden bows and arrows, moulds a piece of wood to make a bow, in his workshop in the town of Lapovo, in central Serbia, Friday, Oct. 27, 2017. — Washington Post, ["AP PHOTOS: Serbian bowyer inspired by childhood games,"](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/ap/article-5179521/AP-PHOTOS-Serbian-bowyer-inspired-childhood-games.html) 14 Dec. 2017
>
> Bow makers, known as *bowyers*, layer the wood with fiberglass, resin and occasionally some carbon (similar to what’s done in ski construction). —
>   Brigid Mander, WSJ, ["Archery: The Ultimate Antidote to Information Overload,"](https://www.wsj.com/articles/archery-the-ultimate-antidote-to-information-overload-1499432401) 6 July 2017

Similarly, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bowyer) only lists a single sense of the word:

> A person who makes or sells archers' bows.

So, **bowyer** seems quite correct and not at all archaic.

---

Meanwhile, [**bower**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bower) (Merriam-Webster), which is a different word, provides no such sense in its definition.

Comment: Thanks. Other than in lexicography, are you able to cite some examples of current usage? The OED's most recent citation is 1862, and the entry hasn't been updated since the 1887 edition of the dictionary.

Comment: @brannerchinese The Merriam-Webster definition provides some current usage examples. I have updated my answer to quote them directly. I fixed one of the links (the one used by M-W was broken) but the other is behind a paywall.

Comment: [Warbow Wales](http://warbowwales.com/contact/4557703064) is run by people who make traditional bows, and describe themselves as *bowyers* (using *bowmen* and *--women* for those who shoot).  They're near where I am now and I had an idea they existed (presumably I've seen something about them).  That seems current enough.

Comment: "Bowyer" is the term you need and even if it sounds old-fashioned no, that doesn't make it "extinct" nor even "obsolescent", let alone "obsolete." It's not archaic; merely specific.

"Bower" is quite diffrent and in no way relevant here.

Comment: This is confirmed by the OED with examples from the 13th to 19th centuries. It does however acknowledge another sense - that of someone who uses a bow. *1862   G. P. Marsh Lect. Eng. Lang. (new ed.) xii. 182   The arrow-makers, or fletchers..had as full a vocabulary as the bowyers.*

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin the obsolescence of "bowyer" is made plain by the fact that the Washington Post and Wall Street Journal both felt compelled to define the term when they used it.

Comment: @phoog Sorry and why is it hard to see that the Washington Post and Wall Street Journal might have felt compelled to define the term at least as much because of their own ignorance or their perception of their readers' ignorance, than anything else?

If you think their reputations sweep away all in their path, have you ever worked with either title, or are you simply relying on their reputations?

Though not the Wall Street Journal, I have worked with the Washington Post, which work taught me not to trust it on any matter requiring research.

What's been your own experience?

Comment: I forgot to mention, some might say the American colonists had less direct memories of their own cultural history but that's not really true, is it? In fact, the Pilgrim Fathers left Britain with exactly the same historical memories as their stay-at-home contemporaries.